# Coverting between javascript keycodes and libgdx keycodes

Tags: gwt, libgdx

I am porting a existing webgame to libgdx. The game is controlled by a script I would rather not change.
The script specifies actions to do on certain keypress events using their javascript keycode value.
ie.  "OnKeyPress=32:" would define actions to run when space is pressed.
"OnKeyPress=40:" would define actions to run when down is pressed, etc.

Now, as LibGDX uses different keycode system I need some way to fire my existing events when the correct key is pressed.

```
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
//convert input processors keycode to javascripts?
}
```

I can only think I have to create some sort of large static hashmap mapping between
GDXs 
*Input.Keys* 
and 
*com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes*

But before going to this bother I thought Id ask around in case theres a better way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just created a class to associate one keycode (com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys) with another. (com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes)

Fairly easy, but anyone doing the same should pay careful attention that not everything has a 1:1 mapping.

For example;

ALT_LEFT and ALT_RIGHT both map to ALT in gwt/javascript.

Likewise CNTR left and right and SHIFT left and right.

GDX meanwhile treats BACKSPACE and DELETE as the same key.

This is, naturally, as GDX needs to be cross platform so has different requirements.

Other then that just a ImmutableMap seemed to do the job....

```
/**
 * static mapping between javascript/gwt keycodes and gdxs
 **/
static ImmutableMap<Integer,Integer> keyCodeConversion = ImmutableMap.<Integer, Integer>builder()
        .put(Input.Keys.UP, GwtKeyCodeCopy.UP)
        .put(Input.Keys.DOWN, GwtKeyCodeCopy.DOWN)
        .put(Input.Keys.LEFT, GwtKeyCodeCopy.LEFT)
        .put(Input.Keys.RIGHT, GwtKeyCodeCopy.RIGHT)
        .....
        ...(lots more)
        .bind();


static public int getJavascriptKeyCode(int GdxKeycode){
    return keyCodeConversion.get(GdxKeycode);
}
```